# Excel export with Image thumbnails

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, custom-actions, thumbnail, export-to-excel

I have a solution on SharePoint Online, in which I using multiple list to read the data from, and I have built a custom button on web page to export/download an excel having transactional data (from 2-3 lists), that include Link address of uploaded images.

Now, the challenge is that I need to showcase the thumbnails of Images instead of image links.

If any body have solution for this!!

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding of your question, you need to show the corresponding Image Thumbnails for the Image URL in the exported excel file as below:

[image]

Actually, it's an Excel limitation rather than a SharePoint issue where the export operation is done successfully from SharePoint to Excel with the correct info as you have said! but the image URL is not rendered to the corresponding image thumbnails by default!

In this case, you have to manually do that in the exported excel file using VBA code as mentioned at [convert the Image URLs To the actual Images With VBA Code](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4212-excel-insert-image-from-url.html)

> Note: [You cannot create or run macros with VBA in Excel for the office for the web](https://debug.to/526/if-there-is-a-way-to-use-vba-macros-to-connect-to-cloud-and-open-excel-workbooks)